# template implemation compatible for pointer in c

Tags: c, templates, gcc, precompile

```
#define MAX_SIZE 32
#define DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(type) \
typedef struct RINGQUEUE_##type{ \
    type data[MAX_SIZE]; \
}RINGQUEUE_##type; \
...someMethod

DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(structA)
DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(int*)
```

the character '*' affect the name of structure, how can i fix this.. 
any preprocessor directive available?
or i must redeclare other definition like

```
#define DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE_ptr(type) \
typedef struct RINGQUEUE_##type{ \
    type* data[MAX_SIZE]; \
}RINGQUEUE_##type; \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "naked" types, I don't think you can do it without the extra macro, since `int` and `*` are two separate tokens.

So your separate macro is a possibility, but I would make a slight change to differentiate between `int` and `int*`:

```
#define DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE_ptr(type) \
    typedef struct RINGQUEUE_ptr_##type{ \
        type *data[MAX_SIZE]; \
    } RINGQUEUE_ptr_##type;
```

As you currently have it, both would create the same `struct` and `typedef` names, leading to errors.

---

However, if you `typedef` the pointer type first so it's presented as *one* token, you *could* use something like:

```
typedef int* pInt;
DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(pInt);
```

That should work, based on the fact that the following code:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 32

#define DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(type) \
    typedef struct RINGQUEUE_##type { \
        type data[MAX_SIZE]; \
    } RINGQUEUE_##type

DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(int);

typedef int* pInt;
DECLEAR_RINGQUEUE(pInt);
```

generates, when passed through the pre-processor:

```
typedef struct RINGQUEUE_int { int data[32]; } RINGQUEUE_int;

typedef int* pInt;
typedef struct RINGQUEUE_pInt { pInt data[32]; } RINGQUEUE_pInt;
```

and compiles without error.

Comment: typedef is nice, ur pretty awesome, buddy